# Iterating through nested dict to display multiple tables

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-table

I'm a bit new to react and trying to get my head around it. I have my `props.items` as the following dict, I managed to fetch it via an API

```
[  
   {  
      "categories":[  
         {  
            "name":"Hot Drinks",
            "menu_items":[  
               {  
                  "name":"Regular Coffee",
                  "__typename":"MenuItem"
               }
            ],
            "__typename":"Category"
         },
         {  
            "name":"Salads",
            "menu_items":[  
               {  
                  "name":"Caesar Salad",
                  "__typename":"MenuItem"
               },
               {  
                  "name":"Cat",
                  "__typename":"MenuItem"
               },
               {  
                  "name":"Custom Salad",
                  "__typename":"MenuItem"
               },
               {  
                  "name":"No Modifier Salad",
                  "__typename":"MenuItem"
               }
            ],
            "__typename":"Category"
         }
      ],
      "__typename":"Vendor"
   }
]
```

What I"m trying to do is display `categories[x].name` as a header, and  `categories[x].menuitems` as a table.

```
   {this.props.items.map(( listValue, index ) => {
      return (
        <tr key={index}>
          <td>{listValue.id}</td>
          <td>{listValue.title}</td>
          <td>{listValue.price}</td>
        </tr>
      );
    })}
```

But this doesn't display anything. How do I get around this ?

Answer (score -1):

I think you wanted to use [Array.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/entries) method, I always start with .items() only to remember that it is called .entries()!

Or maybe you wanted something completely different, here is some version in Vue.js:

```js
const props = [  
   {  
      "categories":[  
         {  
            "name":"Hot Drinks",
            "menu_items":[  
               {  
                  "name":"Regular Coffee",
                  "__typename":"MenuItem"
               }
            ],
            "__typename":"Category"
         },
         {  
            "name":"Salads",
            "menu_items":[  
               {  
                  "name":"Caesar Salad",
                  "__typename":"MenuItem"
               },
               {  
                  "name":"Cat",
                  "__typename":"MenuItem"
               },
               {  
                  "name":"Custom Salad",
                  "__typename":"MenuItem"
               },
               {  
                  "name":"No Modifier Salad",
                  "__typename":"MenuItem"
               }
            ],
            "__typename":"Category"
         }
      ],
      "__typename":"Vendor"
   }
]

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
    props
    }
  },
  
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
   
   <div v-for="cat in props[0].categories"> 
       <div style="font-weight: 700;">{{cat.name}}</div>
     <div>
       <div v-for="(menu_item, i) in cat.menu_items" style="padding-left: 10px;">
         {{i + 1}}. {{menu_item.name}}
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
   
</div>
```